# Permissions not saving

Tags: users

I'm working on a development site. Up until recently I haven't had any trouble with saving permissions, everything was working fine, until I added the different user roles for the site. After I added them all, I went back, and started to assign the correct permissions to the correct users types. I hit save, and... nothing.

No error message, no message at all. And the save didn't take effect. I'm starting my head over why it suddenly just isn't working when it was working before. Is there a limit the the amount of users types that Drupal allows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds a lot like a php runtime issue. PHP has a configuration called [max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php), which you can use to set a limit on the number of input vars php will accept. This will affect the number of $_POST and $_GET variables that can be fed into php. The default is 1000, and I suspect, if you have lots and lots of user type, you're hitting up against this ceiling.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Thanks for the question and answer, Moose and Jance.

Comment: +1 Great tip and I'm sure it would fix it for me but see also answer from Darvanen about editing permissions for a specific role in order that the permissions screen for a specific role has a number of checkboxes that are withing the current max_input_vars

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar problems with permissions in that it won't even render the page, probably because we use roles to differentiate our clients and therefore have more than 100 of them.

Try going directly to `admin/people/permissions/roles`, and edit the permissions for a single role, it works for me.

My guess is it is a memory issue, you could potentially fix it by upping your script allowance in php.ini but that would have repercussions.

Comment: +1 good tip/workaround, this saves having to change the max_input_vars value in the PHP configuration, php.ini and therefore would be a quick fix in the event of emergencies, particularly if a live production server has more restricted access.