# Where do I import a panels variant?

Tags: panels

In the Panels UI, when you are editing a variant, you have the option to **Export** the variant, and the tooltip says "*Export the variant into code to import into another page*."

This is exactly what I would like to do, but where do I paste the code to import it?  When I choose **Add variant**, I don't see an option to import, and I don't see an import option in the Page Manager UI (admin/structure/pages) either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not the super admin (user id = 1) on your drupal site.

You need to give the permission for "Use CTools importer" to be able to import a variant.

Comment: +1 spot on, thank you. I found enabling "Use CTools importer" in role permissions to result in "Import Variant" to now be displayed in the tabs. Generally, when it comes to any permissions adjustments, be aware that if you have a lot of checkboxes/tick boxes on the permissions page, that even if you save, the box may remain unticked because of the setting for maximum input vars - 2 straightforward solutions are here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/142014/1082 or http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/130250/1082 from question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130249

Answer (score 2):

there should be an import button at the top of the page beside the Add Variant:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I have **Disable**, **Add variant**, and **Reorder variants**, but not **Import variant**.  Is there some other dependency I need?

Comment: All I have turned on is Panels, and Panel Nodes to see the import option..

Comment: I took a look at a couple of other sites of mine, one is a near vanilla test site, and they all contain the import variant, one with only Panels enabled. I would suspect something is overriding or interfering in your specific set-up